# How to get value in XSLT based on attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I understand that the colon in XSLT is used as a namespace, but I am running up against a non-namespace issue with colons.

Basically, I need to get the value of a field that has an attribute name with a colon in it.

Example:

```
<root>
    <Name name="Attn:">whatever</Name>
    <Name name="somethingelse">something</Name>
</root>
```

I want to be able to select exactly the name with the "Attn:" attribute so I can change it, so:

```
<root>
   <AttentionName>Whatever</AttentionName>
   <Name>something</Name>
<root>
```

Have tried:

```
<AttentionName>
    <xsl:value-of select="root/Name/@Attn:"/>
</AttentionName>
```

but it errors out stating that the colon cannot be in the select value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute *name* (`name`) does not contain a colon; the attribute *value* (`Attn:`) of `@name` contains a colon.

You can simply adjust your XPath as follows to acquire the string value of the `Name` element whose `@name` attribute equals `Attn:`

```
<AttentionName>
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/Name[@name='Attn:']"/>
</AttentionName>
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for your help! I am new at XSLT, and that was driving me insane.

Comment: I had to come back, didn't let me accept it as the answer until x amount of time had elapsed.